# use CONVERT to convert the special character in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with the values like

```
$array = array('T-106', 'T-125', 'anyname');
$imploade_id = implode(', ', $array);
```

I want to put these result into mysql

```
mysql_query("select * from table_name where userid in ($imploade_id)");
```

But I got an error with this query that is

```
Unknown column 'T' in 'where clause'
```

I also used

```
select * from table_name where userid in ( CONVERT ('T-106' USING urf8) )
```

It works fine for just one id but i don't know how to use with `$implode_id` or with the set of ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace top 2 lines with this

```
$array = array('T-106', 'T-125', 'anyname');
$imploade_id = implode("','", $array);
$imploade_id="'$imploade_id'";
```

and try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put into a database you use `INSERT` and not `SELECT`.

Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (column) values ($imploade_id)");
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply but sorry for the explanation but put means the array into IN operator..